# how to delete specific trigger for a scheduled job

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, job-scheduling

i have created job with like creating with one jobName and different keys(see JobDataMap)

```
CronTriggerImpl trigger = new CronTriggerImpl();
JobDetailImpl jobDetail = null;
trigger.setMisfireInstruction(CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING);
trigger.setName(getUniqueJobId());
trigger.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
trigger.setTimeZone(timeZone);
JobDataMap dataMap = new JobDataMap();
dataMap.put("jobName", "job");
dataMap.put("id", "key");
trigger.setJobDataMap(jobDataMap);
jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl();
jobDetail.setName(getUniqueJobId());
jobDetail.setJobDataMap(jobDataMap);
jobDetail.setJobClass(JobLauncherDetails.class);
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

it is working properly but i want to delete the specific trigger how can i delete
i had seen fee source but those are not matching. please help me out

**Updated : **

i want to delete like
schedule.deleteJob(JobKey) what will be the job key as per my schedule configuration
or should i use schedule.unScheduler()

Answer (score 0):

`org.quartz.Scheduler#unscheduleJob` accepts the trigger key as parameter. Hence, you can remove the trigger specified, not the job.

```
public static boolean removeJob(String jobName, String jobGroup) throws SchedulerException {
  TriggerKey triggerKey = TriggerKey.triggerKey(jobName, jobGroup);
  if (scheduler.checkExists(triggerKey)) {
    scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey);    // trigger + job
  }
  logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>> removeJob success, triggerKey:{}", triggerKey);
  return true;
}
```

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE:**

We don't know actually your functional need. But, you can create Trigger in cleaner way and bind it to a given Job:

```
CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
  .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
  .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/2 8-17 * * ?"))
  .forJob("myJob", "group1") // Binding the Trigger to the Job
  .build();
```

I see you are using `JobDataMap` in your `Trigger`. This is useful for passing parameters to a `Job` that are specific to the executions of the trigger. Do you need really that?

**Useful link:** https://www.baeldung.com/quartz

Comment: as we see in ny question differentiation between triggers is dataMap.put("id", "key"); i gave but here with job name how come it will unschedule specific trigger. and also i am not specifying jobGroup while creating job. i what dont know what jobgroup i need to pass here. sorry if i confuse you, excuse me

Comment: thanks M.Mas. now i cann't change my job scheduling part(scheduling part is working fine mentioned full code in question). what i want is using existing class only i want to unschedule the trigger. or delete specific trigger. pls check my question with updated points